# tax_query: Don’t show posts with parent term when they have a corresponding child term applied

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical, tax-query

I have a hierarchical taxonomy `download-category` from which I only want the posts with a parent term to show up:

```
$downloads_parent_posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'        => 'downloads',
    'orderby'          => 'title',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'download-category',
        'terms'            => $term->term_id,
        'field'            => 'term_id',
        'include_children' => false
      )
    ),
) );
```

This query works fine.

Now what I’d like to achieve is that only posts show up, that don’t have a child of the corresponding parent term applied.

For example I have a parent taxonomy term 'film' and a child term 'horror'. A post has both the parent term and the child term. This post should not show up in that query above.

Is it somehow possible to extend the query or add a condition which filters out the posts with a corresponding child term to the parent term?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see you are trying to be clear but still a really confusingly worded question, broke my brain a bit. I think this might achieve what you want, but I'm not fully sure if I understand you correctly or not. Try it out anyway, it may or may not work:

```
$downloads_parent_posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'        => 'downloads',
    'orderby'          => 'title',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'download-category',
        'terms'            => $term->term_id,
        'field'            => 'term_id',
        'include_children' => false
      ),
      array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'download-category',
        'terms'            => get_term_children($term->term_id, $term->taxonomy),
        'field'            => 'term_id',
        'operator'         => 'NOT IN',
      )
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Sorry for breaking you brain … English is not my first language and sometimes it’s a bit difficult to explain things properly. But many thanks for helping and pointing my brain in the right direction. :D I just needed to change the line `'terms' => get_term_children($term),` to `'terms' => get_term_children( $term->term_id, $taxonomy )`. Now your code works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: All good it needed the challenge. You did well to describe it in a few different ways, I just had to reread it quite a few times to really get it, it's not an easy query to get one's head around. Glad it actually worked! I edited it to add the taxonomy. :-)

Comment: Thanks – I really appreciate your effort. Just one last thing: I also needed to change `$term` to `$term->term_id` in the same line.

Comment: you're welcome. I come on here for questions to challenge myself with. :-) the `get_term_children` function description in the codex implies it will accept a term object as the first argument but whatever works.